# disable or change ribbon keytips shortcut on word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

When I am typing on word and I want to change the language of keyboard several times with 'alt'+'shift' keys. But it is very annoying because when I press 'alt' key It shows ribbon keytips.
I want to know is there any way to disable this or change the key for example to 'ctrl' key? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to change the use of Alt in Word 2016.  Use Control Panel to change Keyboard language to eliminate the conflict.

Open Control Panel.
Under Clock, Language, and Regional Options, click Change keyboard.